# How do I include DRLs that are in a different jar?

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

When I am building up a kjar, how do I include rules from a different kjar in my rulebase?

**Use case:**

I want to build up some rules using the workbench, and other rules at runtime using a custom kjar generator tool. These rules should be combined into a single rulebase at runtime. The generated kjar should reference and import the workbench-created rules.

I have tried setting the static kjar as a dependency of the other kjar in the POM, but the rules don't seem to be imported.

I looked at module inheritance with the **kmodule**, but I'm not sure how this applies. Shouldn't all rule packages in the path be included by default?

I am running the dynamic kjar in a KIE Server container. (v6.5.0.Final)

Answer (score 0):

Do both, add the kjar as a dependency and configure the kmodule. The kmodule is the way to configure the rulesets.

Comment: See my comment to Abhijit's answer

Answer (score 0):

Users need to properly includes the dependent kjar's kbase in kmodule.xml in order to find process in the dependent kjar:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
<kbase name="kbase2">
    <ksession name="ksession2"/>
</kbase>
</kmodule>

 Parent Kjar:

<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
<kbase name="kbase1" includes="kbase2">
    <ksession name="ksession1"/>
</kbase>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried doing this. I found that the client ruleset will not build if the included kbase is missing, so it obviously knows about the other module... but when I execute the rules, it still says a query defined in a DRL in the target module does not exist.

Comment: Do both the client and target have to have sessions explicitly defined? If so, how do they relate to each other? Currently, only the client module defines a named session.